# Logout mechanism not fully effective

Tags: federated-authentication, cookies

We are using Sitecore 9.3.
We have login and logout features in our site using Azure AD B2C.

During logout, we are performing below operations in that order -

1. `AuthenticationManager.Logout()`
2. We send request to Azure AD B2C to logout and send a post logout redirect url
3. Delete the cookie - `.AspNet.Cookie`
4. Calling `HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon()`
5. Calling `HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear()`
6. Calling `Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut()`

In the penetration test done on the site, it was found that even after logging out, calling - `https://portalname/sitecore/api/ssc/item/{item_id}/children`

with `.ASPNet.Cookies` in the header is giving `200 OK` response.

Can anyone please suggest why is application still accepting the value of `.AspNet.Cookies` cookie? How to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a sign-out request to Azure AD B2C because you are "only" logging out user from Sitecore. Upon a sign-out request, Azure AD B2C invalidates the Azure AD B2C cookie-based session, and attempts to sign out from federated identity providers.

You can do it by sending GET request to this url:

> https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms%2F

[image]

You can find more information here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-a-sign-out-request

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. This we are doing already in the Step 2 of logout.